# Generating "better" random data with artificial fluctuations, ebbs and flows

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to build an example chart using ggplot. The context is marketing data and I created some dummy data with these blocks:

```
# dimensions
channels <- c("Facebook", "Youtube", "SEM", "Organic", "Email", "Direct")
last_month <- Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1) %>% floor_date("month")
mts <- seq(from = last_month %m+% months(-23), to = last_month, by = "1 month") %>% format("%b-%Y")
dimvars <- expand.grid(Month = mts, Channel = channels)

# metrics
rws <- nrow(dimvars)
set.seed(123)
Sessions <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 3000, sd = 300))
Transactions <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 200, sd = 40))
Revenue <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 10000, sd = 100))

# make df
dataset <- cbind(dimvars, Sessions, Transactions, Revenue)
```

I then build an area plot:

```
timeline <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions,fill = Channel, group = Channel)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Here's how it looks:
[image]

This image is pretty unrealistic from the standpoint of a marketer, where all channels are moving in line with each other. Short of actually adding in manual values, I wondered if there are any techniques for adding multipliers or similar to "random" data?

For example, without resorting to adding manual values, I'd like to know if I can set the `rnorm()` to start with a lower mean, then grow, then shrink again along the n values generated. Is there a function that does this? I could create 3 or 4 distributions with different means and then `c()` them but this would look more like sharp changes rather than gradual ebbs and flows.

Any suggestions for manipulating random data to fluctuate (expand and contract) over the course of n length vector?

I tried fiddling with the sd argument or rnorm but that just made the data look more volatile.

I'm trying to show, somewhat randomly, channels start and ramp up, then level off and decline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a simple distribution, you may take a look at random walks/Brownian motion.

For example:

```
randwalk <- function(initial_val, ...){
  initial_val + cumsum(rnorm(...))
}

randwalk(550, n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 20)
```

Which has movements similar to that of stocks. Tweaking the mean ever so slightly can give slightly rising or slightly falling over time values.

Comment: HI thanks for answering. I'm not following the randwalk function, could you break it down? Is "initial_val" my original Sessions vector? What is the second line doing?

Comment: `rnorm` generates random values from a normal distribution. `cumsum` gives the cumulative sum of those values. `initial_val` just shifts all the values up or down by an amount equal to `initial_val`. Try this: `x=rnorm(10); x`, then `cumsum(x)` then `cumsum(x) + 10`

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 for explaining that, well said. + 1

Comment: Generally random walks start out at some initial value, and then for each successive step, they randomly move either up or down by a small amount. In the long run they should end up near the mean, but over short periods, multiple "ups" in a row gives values a fair bit higher than the mean.

Comment: Is 550 just an arbitrary starting point to generate the vectors of n = 144 (the dataframe should be 144 observation (variable rws is 144). I tried running the same code block but replacing how I initially defined Sessions above with `Sessions <- ceiling(randwalk(550, n = rws, mean = 3000, sd = 300))`. The visual does change but the metrics all rise in a straight, steady upwards line. I'm not sure if I've misunderstood who to use it or if this is expected behavior?

Comment: Arbitrary. You want `ceiling(randwalk(3000, n = 144, mean = 0, sd = 300))` or some small small variation of that mean value (0.01 for example).

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! I though tit was a long shot when I posted but my chart is looking ace. Thank you very much for your help. I'm still struggling to understand what's going on here though. I'll stare at it a bit more, I just had a big lunch maybe that's why (Asia).

Comment: It's the mean = 0 part that's throwing me of. Why would we set it to zero when calling randwalk while setting "initial_value" to be what was previously the mean? (I'll delete my recent comments after for tidyness)

Comment: No problem. I encourage you to reread eipi10 and Marius' comment above to solidify what is happening. To reiterate, previously you generated data entirely using rnorm. The mean value you entered (3000) meant each additional datapoint generated from `rnorm()` was to be somewhat near 3000. Now, however, we are doing 'cumsum(rnorm())'. This means that if you left 3000 as the mean, the first value would be 3000, and the second value near 6000, and so forth. That's not what you want. You want a slight up or down, randomly moving and changing slightly from what was before it. Thus mean = ~ 0.

Comment: Think of a random walk as having a memory of what was done before it. It is randomly taking steps up or down from the prior value. We want to start our journey from 3000 and let the randomness of our average step (0 or 0.01 if you want slightly up over time) move the values large amounts over time. You could end up with drastically different time series each time you run the code.

Comment: Yup, it's clicking now (I think). The magic comes from cumsum() function if I understand it right. We are adding to our desired Avg. value 3000 a + or - an rnorm with mean 0

Comment: Exactly. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: If you plot a few examples, it will probably be much clearer. Try `plot(cumsum(rnorm(100)))` and `plot(cumsum(rnorm(100))+10)` a few times each.

Comment: Yes or `plot.ts(replicate(6,cumsum(rnorm(100))))` for same screen viewing